# Download File from given URL in C#

Tags: c#, url, download

I want to create a functionality that allow my web application to download the file from given URL after every hour.

Should be something like this :

1. It goes to given URL, download the zip file (eg - http://www.abc.com/FileFolder/GetUrFile.aspx?username=abc&password=000&filename=abc.zip)
2. Then Unzip and extract that file by code
3. Put that file in specific folder
4. Repeat this process after every 1 or 2 hours

Thanking You,
Ram Vinay Kumar

Answer (score 3):

Your solution would be in 3 steps:

**1. Download file from URL** 
Have a look at `System.Net.WebClient`

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient ())
{
    Client.DownloadFile("http://www.abc.com/file/song/a.mpeg", "a.mpeg");
}
```

**2. Unzip the file** 
In .Net 4.5, you can look at `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`

```
string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Or probably look into `SharpZipLib` if you want more robust solution to unzip

**3. Scheduler** 
you can look at `System.Timers`;

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
```

Combine these and code your solution.

Comment: @Loki-
Can you please share the CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath); and ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath); method which you guided me to do this..

Comment: @ShubhVinay you need to add reference for `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`. Then include the library with `using System.IO.Compression`, followed by calling ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory or ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory